# Service for finding players and planning online game sessions?

Tags: xbox-network

I would like a good list of services for planning online gaming sessions. So far I have not even found one good service for this. Best would be if it could integrate with social accounts out there like Facebook, Google Plus or Xbox Live and anything else alike.

Especially I need this service for games not to often played online anymore.

For example I only once seen another player in the Renegade Ops (XBox 360 version) online multiplayer lobby. That's really a shame as that game probably rocks 4 player co-op.

Maybe we can create this list here? But any answer with a good service making is possible to reach out to other possible Renegade Ops players out there would be a good answer.

Comment: Why the dislike?

Comment: @Tim - This question just seems off topic.  Similar to a game rec.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are considered off-topic for this site, as they do not work well in a Q&A format. [Here is a link to a related StackExchange blog post about these types of questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would to start a thread on a forum somewhere where there are lots of XBOX users, and find some friends that would be willing to play with you. As for my knowledge, the only service out there would be another forum thread. There are no Databases (that I know of) that show active players of games. There might be a list of people who have "played" the game, but if they still play it would be the important part.